# Function in BaseSpider class to yield a request

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to create a function that takes care of a recurring task in multiple spiders. It involves yielding a request that seems to break it. This question is a follow-up from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44198404/write-functions-for-all-scrapy-spiders).

```
import scrapy
import json
import re

class BaseSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    start_urls = {}

    def test(self, response, cb, xpath):
        self.logger.info('Success')
        for url in response.xpath(xpath).extract():
            req = scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(url), callback=cb)
            req.meta['category'] = response.meta.get('category')
            yield req
```

When the `yield req` is in the code, the "Success" logger suddenly does not work anymore and the callback function does not seem to be called. When `yield req` is commented, the logger does show the "Success" logger. Although I don't think the issue is in the spider, below the code of the spider:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from crawling.spiders import BaseSpider

class testContactsSpider(BaseSpider):
    """ Test spider """
    name = "test"
    start_urls = {}
    start_urls['test'] = 'http://www.thewatchobserver.fr/petites-annonces-montres#.WfMaIxO0Pm3'

    def parse(self,response):
        self.logger.info('Base page: %s', response.url)
        self.test(response, self.parse_page, '//h3/a/@href')

    def parse_page(self, response):
        self.logger.info('Page: %s', response.url)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need something like this:

```
   def parse(self,response):
    self.logger.info('Base page: %s', response.url)
    for req in self.test(response, self.parse_page, '//h3/a/@href'):
        yield req
```

Test method yields results and thats why it return generator type. 
Try code from below and read this for [Understanding Generators in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756096/understanding-generators-in-python):

```
def test():
  print('Inside generator!')
  for i in range(5):
    yield i

print('============')
g = test() #save as variable
test()     #trying to call func
print('============')
print(next(g)) #next of "g" generator
print(next(g))
print('============')
print(next(test())) #next of newly created generator
print(next(test()))
print('============')
for i in test(): #for each elem that returns generator
  print(i)
```

In this example we not using generator:

```
self.test(response, self.parse_page, '//h3/a/@href')
```

In this we trying to get next element and thats why it's called:

```
    self.test(response, self.parse_page, '//h3/a/@href').next()
#or
    next(self.test(response, self.parse_page, '//h3/a/@href'))
```

Comment: this seems to work indeed. However, ideally I'd like to make my code as simple as possible. It's not possible to have these requests yielded directly in the `self.test` function without doing a loop in the `self.parse` function?

Comment: I don't think that is possible. If you want to keep code a little simpler (_in python 3_) you can use `yield from test()` instead of `for req in test(): yield req`.

Comment: Unfortunately I’m running 2.7 but thanks for your help